# Universal Ad-Hoc version does install on ipad, but not on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, adhoc

I have encountered a weird problem, when i built my last ad-hoc version for our customer.
The app is a universal app. Deployment Target is ios 4.3.
The ad-hoc installs perfectly on the customers ipad, but not on his iphone. I tested it with our iphones and we have the same problem.

Ad hoc installs on ipad, but not on iphone.

- All devices are listed in the provisioning profile.
- The provisioning profile is valid and also are the certificates valid.
- Entitlements are deactivated.

Has anyone any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to reinstall the profiles on the phone again? On my ad-hoc distributions it almost turned out that something was wrong with the profiles.

Comment: The problem is, that i use two different profiles. One for us for testing and one for our customers for testing. It would be really unlikely that both profiles are damaged at the same time. But i'll try it. Maybe it works and then I'll be happy :)

Comment: I observed such a behaviour when e.g. a certificate expired and had to be renewed then other, dependant stuff had to be regenerated again. Just an idea. By the way I started like this with customers but meanwhile I think if the customer provides all bundle ids and certificates one need for dev and testing you are on the save side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the provisioning profile from the organizer, download it again from the portal and install it.